# Zend LDAP Auth : "Invalid credentials" using the good password

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework, ldap

In my app, I authenticate users using Zend Ldap adapter, when I use my Ldap account, Ldap return "Invalid credentials".

I ask some work mates to login with my app using their Ldap credentials, it worked! They have the same Ldap account configuration as me (group).

So I changed my Ldap password to 123456, and when I try to login, it worked!

I changed again my Ldap password to the original one, its length is 8 and it contains only alphanum caracters. And retry to login, it failed again!

I don't understand what is bad in my password because some of my work mates have stronger password which work (with some special caracters).

Any idea ?

Comment: Wrong encoding maybe?

Comment: I don't think, because other accounts work.

Comment: Well, I took a look at the request sent to my AD server and it received my password in lowercase... I don't understand why, I'm investigating...